# jupyter notebook doesn't open: Access Denied

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ubuntu-20.04

### Info:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 20.04
- **Distribution**: Anaconda 2020.07 Linux x86_64
- **Current Default Browser**: Firefox 81.0 64-bit

### What I do:

- Open terminal
- cd to a specific path
- Run `jupyter notebook`

### What happens:

- Firefox opens up but shows this message:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:8888/tree?

    Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

**Note**: I used to use **Google Chrome** as my default browser and it worked fine. But I decided to switch to Firefox and not once I could use Jupyter in Firefox.

**P.S**: I don't want to switch back to Chrome again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur when you use the proxy. You can disable proxy and run Jupyter!

Comment: Thank you very much Mohammad. It was the problem!